# Re-read an open file Python

Tags: python, file, testing

I have a script that reads a file and then completes tests based on that file however I am running into a problem because the file reloads after one hour and I cannot get the script to re-read the file after or at that point in time.

So:

- GETS NEW FILE TO READ
- Reads file
- performs tests on file
- GET NEW FILE TO READ (with same name - but that can change if it is part of a solution)
- Reads new file
- perform same tests on new file

Can anyone suggest a way to get Python to re-read the file?

Comment: what have you tried ? Could you show us some code ? What's the exact problem ?

Comment: How can we show you how to fix it if you don't show us your code?

Comment: Move the cursor to the beginning of the file-  fp.seek(0) and then  fp.read()

Comment: The answers don't mention it explicitly, but when you read a file, the file object's position moves to the end of the file. The position is automatically reset when you `open` the file again, or you can manually set it with `f.seek`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Either `seek` to the beginning of the file

```
with open(...) as fin:
    fin.read()   # read first time
    fin.seek(0)  # offset of 0
    fin.read()   # read again
```

or open the file again (I'd prefer this way since you are otherwise keeping the file open for an hour doing nothing between passes)

```
with open(...) as fin:
    fin.read()   # read first time

with open(...) as fin:
    fin.read()   # read again
```

Putting this together

```
while True:
    with open(...) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            # do something 
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: I think it is still better to keep the file opened and re-read it, open and close operations are very costly.
You took a workaround by adding a sleep call.

Comment: @AhmedHamdy, Leaving files open also has a cost. It's not so much a problem now days, but it used to be easy to run out of file descriptors if you were opening a lot of files. It's a balance you need to manage depending on the situation.

Comment: Just a small point:  for files opened in append mode (ie., in order to create them without overwriting them if they already existed) you can't seek do seek(0)

Answer (score 20):

You can move the cursor to the beginning of the file the following way:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Then you can successfully read it.