# difference bwtween pickle.load(p) versus pickle.load(urllib.open(link))

Tags: python, pickle

Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| IPython 5.4.1

I do not understand why depending on how I give the arguments to pickle, I am getting the desired result or an error
Please, take a look to this example:

```
import urllib
import pickle

p= pickle.load(urllib.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p"))

link='http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p'
q= pickle.load(urllib.urlopen(link))
```

and I get the data for p and q (list 23 elements)

However, 
If I try:

```
   f = urllib.urlopen(link)   
   r= pickle.load(f)
```

I get:

```
raise EOFError
```

If I try:

```
myfile = f.read()
s= pickle.load(myfile)
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

I search in SO for similar solutions, but I failed to find one that could give me an answer.

Can anyone help me to understand why r and s failed, when q and f look the same to me?

******EDITED TO RESPONSE DAVIS HERRING   ********

```
import urllib
import pickle

link="http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)   
#myfile = f.read()

r= pickle.load(f)
```

Removing myfile = f.read(), makes r to work. You were right! Now I understand your answer, I cannot read f then use it on load(). However, it looks reading f changes f?

Ok, I found an answer on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021863/re-read-an-open-file-python)

Comment: Did you evaluate the assignments to `f` and `r` just once each?

Comment: yes.. just how appear in my code... not sure if I understood your question thought.

Comment: You can’t pass `f` to `pickle.load` *and* (usefully) call `read` on it.  Show *one* example, or else one *complete* example per attempt.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood your comment, and you are right. I Edited my answer to show the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t affect `pickle.load` to attach or not attach a *name* (`f`) to the file object returned by `urllib.urlopen(link)`.  (Attaching a name does have another advantage, which is that you can `close` it properly—use `with`—rather than automatically and unreliably.)

However, what is returned is a **stream**—a *source* of data rather than a *container* of it.  It can’t be `read` twice (or `read` and also `load`ed) because it doesn’t store a copy of anything (which can be important for large files/pages).

If you *do* have the data in a (byte) **string**, use [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads).