# for loop is only reading the first line from a file

Tags: python

I have two files, the first file is a list of item with the items listed one per line. The second file is a tsv file with many items listed per line. So, some lines in the second file have items that might be listed in the first file. I need to generate a list of lines from the second file that might have items listed in the first file.

grep -f is being finicky for me so I decided to make my own python script. This is what I came up with:-

Big list is the second file, tiny list is the first file.

```
def main():
    desired_subset = []
    small_list = open('tiny_list.txt','r')
    big_list = open('big_list.tsv','r')
    for i in small_list.readlines():
        i = i.rstrip('\n')
        for big_line in big_list:
            if i in big_line:
                if i not in desired_subset:
                    desired_subset.append(big_line)
    print(desired_subset)
    print(len(desired_subset))

 
main()
```

The problem is that the for loop is only reading through the first line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-read an open file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021863/re-read-an-open-file-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over file (here over `big_list`) you "consume it, so that on the second iteration of `small_list` you don't have anything left in `big_list`. Try reading `big_list` with `.readlines()` into the list variable before the main `for` loop and use that:

```
def main():
    desired_subset = []
    small_list = open('tiny_list.txt','r')
    big_list = open('big_list.tsv','r').readlines() # note here
    for i in small_list.readlines():
        i = i.rstrip('\n')
        for big_line in big_list:
            if i in big_line:
                if i not in desired_subset:
                    desired_subset.append(big_line)
    print(desired_subset)
    print(len(desired_subset))
```

Also, you don't close your files which is a bad practice. I'd suggest to use context manager (open files with `with` statement):

```
def main():
    desired_subset = []
    with open('tiny_list.txt','r') as small_list,
         open('big_list.tsv','r') as big_list:

         small_file_lines = small_list.readlines()
         big_file_lines = big_list.readlines()

    for i in small_file_lines:
        i = i.rstrip('\n')
        for big_line in big_file_lines:
            if i in big_line:
                if i not in desired_subset:
                    desired_subset.append(big_line)

    print(desired_subset)
    print(len(desired_subset))
```

Comment: That sorta fixed the problem, but now I have repeats. I will have to see why the if not in check is not working.Thanks man!

Comment: desired_subset = list(dict.fromkeys(desired_subset)), I added this one line to remove repeats.