# A question about 'readlines' and 'split()'

Tags: python, split, readlines

For a file contains two strings: True and 26. When I use readlines to get those strings:

```
a, b = file.readlines()\[1\].split()
print(a, b)
\# True 26
```

the result is two strings: True and 26. However, when I just want to get the string '26' and added another line after them:

```
a, b = file.readlines()\[1\].split()
print(a, b)
\# True 26
c = file.readlines()\[1\].split()\[1\]
\# IndexError: list index out of range
```

a index error occurs. I do not understand why this happens.

The result should be 26, so how to debug that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Python.

When you use `readlines` multiple times it countinues reading from where it last stopped. When you run the line two times you will receive an empty array the second time and thus IndexError on `file.readlines()[1]`. Either open the file for reading again or keep the value the first time.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. But is there any way to re-zero the counter without closing the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021863/re-read-an-open-file-python